# buffered reader and file.delete

Tags: java, exception, bufferedreader

I'm creating a mini program that deletes Files using the File.delete() method but I'm having a little bit of an issue if I use the buffered Reader to read the .txt file before I delete it, it doesn't delete the file. I did come up with a solution for it: I just close the buffered reader before I delete the file. however this doesn't make sense to me as to why this is happening can anyone explain this.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;

public class Purge {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String sample;
        boolean result = false;


        BufferedReader amg = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/Steven/Desktop/me.txt"));
        sample = amg.readLine();
        amg.close();// closes the buffered reader 
                System.out.println("Haha I'm stille here: "+sample);
        File anesu = new File("C:/Users/Steven/Desktop/me.txt");

        if (anesu.exists()){

        try{result = anesu.delete();

        }catch( Exception x){
            System.out.println("Problem Deleting File"+x);
        }
        catch( Throwable e){
            System.out.println("Problem Deleting File Throwable"+e);
        }

        }else{
            System.out.println("No File ");
        }
        System.out.println("File has been deleted: "+result);

    }

}
```

Comment: I am not sure of file locking behavior java (or windows) but isn't wrong to delete a file which is open (possibly still being used) by `BufferedReader` to be deleted by another `File` object? It generally expected that you close all files before you attempt to delete them.

Comment: What doesn't make sense here is trying to delete a file that you still have open for reading. Make up your mind whether you're trying to read the file or delete it. You can't do both at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a stream object is garbage collected, its finalizer closes the underlying file descriptor. So, the fact that the delete only works when you added the **System.gc()** call is strong evidence that your code is somehow failing to close some stream for the file. It may well be a different stream object to the one that is opened in the code that you posted.

Note :

*Properly written stream handling code uses a finally block to make sure that streams get closed no matter what.*

If you does not want to use **System.gc()**, read your content with FileInputStream

```
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/temp/test.txt"));
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            out.append(line);
         }
         System.out.println(out.toString());   //Prints the string content read from input stream
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {//TODO}
    finally {
         reader.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the file in the `finally` block.
A downside to this approach is that if an exception is thrown the file will still be deleted.

```
public Stream<String> readLines(Path archive) {
        try {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    (new FileInputStream(archive.toFile()))));

            return bufferedReader.lines();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        } finally {
            try {
                Files.delete(archive);
                System.out.println("Deleted: " + archive);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to delete: " + archive);
            }
        }
    }
```